# Cannot move project as it overlaps... Git/Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, git, github

I am trying to move a project into my git repo, using Team -> Share Project -> Git, when I select the repo the error "Cannot move project x to target location...as this location overlaps with location..."

My workspace and repo are different folders (this seems to fix it for most people).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Which version of eclipse and egit plugin are you using?

For me on Kepler Service Release 2 and Egit 3.2.0 it works if I choose:

`Team->Share Project->Git`

and then tickbox `Use or create repository in parent folder of project` *BUT* then select the project folder `.` **instead** of the parent `..`

Answer (score 3):

In my case, there was a `.project` file inside the **git repo**. I just deleted it from the terminal. Then everything works perfectly. You can't access it with the GUI which is another reason why terminal is awesome!

Answer (score 2):

Tried many options but they didn't work. I've posted an answer in another similar question which is a manual way to do it which will work with any Eclipse version, here is the link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41799215/578046

Answer (score 1):

I got this error when attempting to bring in a new subproject into an existing parent project in a "split" workspace i.e. the default configuration using separate workspace and git folders.

The final workaround was different from others listed:

1. Delete the project from within Eclipse (choose default option: *DO NOT delete on filesystem*)
2. Use the system shell move the new subproject from the Workspace location into its proper place under the parent project in the git folder structure
3. In Eclipse, go to the the **Git Repositories** view, right-click the new project folder under *Working Tree*, and choose "*Import Projects...*" to reimport the project
4. Re-add the project to any Working Sets it needs to be part of

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem, and used the following steps to solve the problem:
1、`Team --> Share Project...`
2、**Check** `Use or create repository in parent folder of project`,and then **Check** `Your project...`
3、**Click** `Create Repository`
4、**Click** `Finish`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and realized that when i cloned the git repository i selected the `"import all existing Eclipse projects after clone finishes"` checkbox.  So i removed my repository and cloned it again without the checkbox selected.  Then i had no problem sharing a new Java project into my repository (because no `.project` file was created on the git folder)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, here's how I solved it:

Open The Git Repositories View:

```
Window -> Show View -> Other -> Git -> Git Repositories -> Open
```

Then **Right Click** `YourRepositoryName` in the Git Repositories View and **Click** `Clean...`

A Popup Window will open, **Tick** the `.project` file and **Click** `Finish`

Now when you try to use `Team -> Share Project -> Git` it should work.

If `Clean...` doesn't delete the `.project` file, you can also manually do it by opening the repository file system in the Git Repositories View and look for the `.project` file then **Right Click** the file and **Click** `Delete`

Answer (score 0):

I just went to git folder using terminal and entered the command  rm .project. The problem went away.

Comment: YMMV, this depends on project structure. If your root folder contains a parent project, this solution will cause other problems.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error once, which was caused by the name of my folder containing spaces, e.g. "Joe Doe".

Moving the project to a place where it doesn't have any space in file path solved my problem.

Comment: Welcome to SO @Xiao Yong Kong. It is always good to focus on the answer, and the operating system. Also note how old a question is and if your answer is already covered by other responses, this will help the SO clean.