# Target location for project " " already exists, can not move project

Tags: eclipse, git, import, project

when I am trying to share my project with git repository getting exception like this

> "Target location for project " " already exists, can not move project"

[image]

Comment: What's not clear in the error message you're getting?

Comment: Project already exist in your local repo, you have to import it from your local repo TO eclipse workspace, then do your modifications while connected to it.

Comment: I tried by importing from local repo still same issue

Comment: @flafoux So what happens when you want to commit locally and upstream what you have in your workspace to an existing repo. I have this issue and get the above message too.

Comment: @ShylendraMadda Can you take a look at my answer I posted some time back and see if it resolves your issue and if it does would appreciate if you can mark it as an accepted answer. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for your time but It's no need now. It was already fixed. @SaurabhPatil

Answer (score 10):

Writing an answer because I tried many options suggested in many similar questions but none worked. Then I did it manually with following steps that worked, and **these steps will work for any Eclipse version**:

1. Goto the Eclipse workspace in the file system and copy the project from there and paste it in some other location in your file system. This will serve as a backup.
2. Goto your Eclipse and then right click on the project and click delete. You can say delete from the file system because you've already taken a backup in step1.
3. Goto your Git repo in the file system and paste the project folder at the location you want (may be inside another folder with .project file doesn't matter).
4. Then come back to your Eclipse and then File->Import -> Import from Git -> Local repo -> Select the Git local repo where you've pasted the project in step 3 and then import it as usual.

As I said earlier, this will work for any Eclipse version.

Answer (score 2):

This situation will happen if you already have a Project of the same name in your local git repository. Sharing a project means steps to commit your project into your local git repository and from there it as ORIGIN will be pushed to Master (Remote). (You are creating again with a new eclipse IDE, or that project was deleted from IDE but committed to local repository in the past).

Solution is simple:

1. Remove the project from your local git repository.
   `C:\Users\username\git` on windows operating system. (If this not possible then next step)
2. Rename the project in your IDE (Better recreate a project with same code but with new Project name) that you want to share: repeat the process of sharing on Eclipse IDE.
3. You may optionally want to recreate after dropping the remote repository(master), if something is already pushed from last push of project, so that everything is clean. You may visit the git repository to confirm it.

Answer (score 1):

In my case this was caused by an extraneous `.project` and related Eclipse files at the top of the git repository folder. The files were created by Eclipse due to incorrect folder specified on Import of the other projects in the repo.